# Cannot start mysql transaction in php fork

Tags: php, mysql, pcntl

I have problem when start mysql transaction in child process with php pcntl_fork. The error message is:

```
PDO::beginTransaction(): send of 22 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe
```

How to start transaction in child process with pcntl_fork

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If someone is struggling with this issue, here is the fix:

Try changing/setting up wait_timeout in your mysql my.cnf config file:

```
wait_timeout=3600
```

This config file is located in the **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** (Ubuntu/Debian) and **/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf** (OSX).

Restart mysql server and it should work.

Comment: Bhavin Solanki: Thank you for your reply, now that error message not shown but other errors appear. This is new error:

PDO::query(): MySQL server has gone away
PDO::query(): Error reading result set's header

Comment: This happens because the PHP script took too long to process whatever it was processing, and the connection to the server timed out. You have a few solutions:

1) Check to make sure the connection is still up, and reconnect if needed (mysql_connect has built-in functionality to do that for you)
 2)  Use mysql_pconnect (but remember to close the connection at the end because it won't close for you)
3)   Improve the running time of your script to avoid the timeout.